# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to access an Oracle database table using a python script.
I have written following code:

```
 import cx_Oracle

 con = cx_Oracle.connect("system/infy123@127.0.0.1/XE")
 cur = con.cursor()
 cur.execute(" SELECT * FROM SUPPLIER")
 for row in cursor.fetchall(): 
      print(row)
```

and the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ADMIN/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36- 
32/my_file.py", line 6, in <module>
    cur.execute(" SELECT * FROM SUPPLIER")
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this error?

Comment: maybe table `SUPPLIER` does not exist?

Comment: Table Supplier do exist. I can access it on oracle application express sql workshop.

Comment: Distinct servers specified in application and in code? Insufficient user privileges?

Comment: Servers are correct. I think its the issue of user privileges.
can you tell me how to check and solve it

Comment: sorry mate, I'm not a DBA :) I just faced this kind of issue number of times and it always was a problem with privileges

Answer (score 8):

I bet it's a schema name issue. You connect as user `SYSTEM`, but want to select from a table called `SUPPLIER` which is very likely not in the schema `SYSTEM`.

You can find out where the table is by running in the Apex SQL workshop:

```
SELECT owner FROM all_tables WHERE table_name = 'SUPPLIERS';
```

You'll need to put the owner in front of the table. For instance, if the last query returned 'MYUSER', you'll need to change the query to

```
cur.execute(" SELECT * FROM MYUSER.SUPPLIER")
```

Comment: Your welcome! You might want to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer...

Comment: Helped me determine I was connecting to the incorrect environment and the schema name was just slightly different.